# Customise Previous and Next Buttons of Banner Slider in Spartacus Storefront

Tags: angular, typescript, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am looking to customise Previous and Next Slider buttons on Banner Component in Spartacus Storefront. I am looking to add some custom logic on click of slide button (previous & next). Is there anyway we can get access to these two buttons in our custom component and customize logic?

- I have implemented the banner using typeCode
- 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.